# Semantic UI modal updated settings not triggered on 'hide'

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, jquery-events

I can correctly create a semantic-ui modal element and change the default settings for `transition` and `duration` on page load.  But when I try to modify these settings to hide the modal through `onApprove`, it still uses the same settings that were used with the initial show.  Here's the relevant JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').modal({
    transition: 'horizontal flip',
    duration: 2000,
    onApprove: function() {
      $('#test').modal({
        transition: 'fade',
        duration: 10000
      }).modal('hide');
    }
  }).modal('show');
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfjsmn59/) that demonstrates the issue.  Clicking the 'OK' button should trigger a fade lasting 10 seconds.  The strange thing is I can put a breakpoint in the code after triggering the `onApprove` and see that the settings did indeed get updated to correct values (eg. in semantic.js, line 9001) and the transition runs correctly when I hit 'resume' (Chrome 51.0.2704.103, Windows).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you may apply the new modal setting immediately after the modal is shown in the screen. Like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').modal({
    transition: 'horizontal flip',
    duration: 2000,
    onShow: function() {
      $('#test').modal({
        transition: 'fade',
        duration: 10000
      })
    },
    onApprove: function(){
        $('#test').modal('hide');
    }
  }).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='test' class='ui large modal'>
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      This is the content
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui ok green basic button">
        OK
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That did the trick.  It's as if the new settings don't take effect before the modal hide, but triggering the settings change on show seems like an elegant workaround.